# twisted connectTCP with IPv6

Tags: python, twisted, ipv6

How can I access an IPv6 address with twisted and listenTCP? If I take the address from ifconfig, with e.g. aaa::bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee then I get the following error message:

```html
raise CannotListenError(self.interface, self.port, le)
twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on aaa::bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee
```

Comment: Functions that have `connect` in them are usually in reference to client functionality. However the error is from a server. So are you having issues connecting to the server or with the server listening on a host/port?

Answer (score 0):

Either `endpoints.serverFromString` that specify an IPv6 interface value or explicitly call `endpoints.TCP6ServerEndpoint`.

```py
from twisted.internet import endpoints, protocol, reactor

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        print(f"{type(self.transport)}")

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

# Use one of the following
# Server string, note the backslashes
tcp6 = endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, "tcp:8000:interface=\:\:1")
# Or explicit IPv6 endpoint
tcp6 = endpoints.TCP6ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8000, interface="::1")

factory = protocol.Factory.forProtocol(Echo)
tcp6.listen(factory)
reactor.run()
```

If that doesn't work, then you might need to make sure IPv6 is enabled on your system.